# foreach loop not showing data

Tags: php, foreach

I am having a strange issue with the output of data for my foreach loop.  The loop is not showing the data for the `$image->thumbname`,`$description` or `$id` but the `print_r($get_images);` works fine

**Print_r Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [id] => 1 
            [description] => testing 
            [imagename] => test.jpg 
            [thumbname] => test_thumb.jpg 
) )
```

**View:**

```
<?php if(is_array($get_images)): ?>
    <? print_r($get_images); ?>
        <?php foreach($get_images as $image): ?>
        <img src ="<?=base_url()?>includes/uploads/gallery/thumbs/<?=$image->thumbname?>" alt="<?= $image->description?>"> <a href="deleteimage/<?=$image->id?>">Delete</a>
        <?php print_r($image); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `$image["thumbname"]` and not `$image->thumbname`.

Answer (score 2):

youre using `->` to access the array contents youre supposed to use `[]`

```
<?php if(is_array($get_images)): ?>
    <? print_r($get_images); ?>
        <?php foreach($get_images as $image): ?>
        <img src ="<?=base_url()?>includes/uploads/gallery/thumbs/<?= $image['thumbname'] ?>" alt="<?= $image['description'] ?>"> <a href="deleteimage/<?= $image['id'] ?>">Delete</a>
        <?php print_r($image); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array from what I can tell:

```
$image['thumbname']
```